# BLE connection timeout on Pi3 B+

Tags: pi-3b+, bluetooth

With a Pi 3B and a Pi Zero I'm able to connect to a BLE device without problem, but if I try to connect to the same BLE device with a Pi 3B+ it connect and disconnect after 1s with a timeout error :

**bluetoothctl**

```
[bluetooth]# paired-devices
Device 04:EE:03:B1:47:DF 315X
[bluetooth]# connect 04:EE:03:B1:47:DF
Attempting to connect to 04:EE:03:B1:47:DF
[CHG] Device 04:EE:03:B1:47:DF Connected: yes
Connection successful
[CHG] Device 04:EE:03:B1:47:DF ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Device 04:EE:03:B1:47:DF ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device 04:EE:03:B1:47:DF Connected: no
```

**hcidump**

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo hcidump -t -x
HCI sniffer - Bluetooth packet analyzer ver 5.50
device: hci0 snap_len: 1500 filter: 0xffffffff
2020-09-03 08:38:54.408370 < HCI Command: LE Set Scan Parameters (0x08|0x000b) plen 7
    type 0x00 (passive)
    interval 60.000ms window 30.000ms
    own address: 0x00 (Public) policy: All
2020-09-03 08:38:54.408744 > HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4
    LE Set Scan Parameters (0x08|0x000b) ncmd 1
    status 0x00
2020-09-03 08:38:54.408780 < HCI Command: LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) plen 2
    value 0x01 (scanning enabled)
    filter duplicates 0x01 (enabled)
2020-09-03 08:38:54.409133 > HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4
    LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) ncmd 1
    status 0x00
2020-09-03 08:38:54.418195 > HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 43
    LE Advertising Report
      ADV_NONCONN_IND - Non connectable undirected advertising (3)
      bdaddr 33:3C:4F:34:0D:15 (Random)
      Unknown type 0xff with 29 bytes data
      RSSI: -87
2020-09-03 08:38:54.427065 > HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 33
    LE Advertising Report
      ADV_IND - Connectable undirected advertising (0)
      bdaddr 04:EE:03:B1:47:DF (Public)
      Flags: 0x06
      Unknown type 0x06 with 16 bytes data
      RSSI: -63
2020-09-03 08:38:54.427107 < HCI Command: LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) plen 2
    value 0x00 (scanning disabled)
    filter duplicates 0x00 (disabled)
2020-09-03 08:38:54.428413 > HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4
    LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) ncmd 1
    status 0x00
2020-09-03 08:38:54.428443 < HCI Command: LE Create Connection (0x08|0x000d) plen 25
    bdaddr 04:EE:03:B1:47:DF type 0
    interval 96 window 96 initiator_filter 0
    own_bdaddr_type 0 min_interval 24 max_interval 40
    latency 0 supervision_to 42 min_ce 0 max_ce 0
2020-09-03 08:38:54.428968 > HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
    LE Create Connection (0x08|0x000d) status 0x00 ncmd 1
2020-09-03 08:38:54.468505 > HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 19
    LE Connection Complete
      status 0x00 handle 64, role master
      bdaddr 04:EE:03:B1:47:DF (Public)
2020-09-03 08:38:54.468677 < HCI Command: LE Read Remote Used Features (0x08|0x0016) plen 2
  40 00
2020-09-03 08:38:54.469375 > HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
    LE Read Remote Used Features (0x08|0x0016) status 0x00 ncmd 1
2020-09-03 08:38:54.469383 > HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 14
    LE Read Remote Used Features (0x08|0x0016) ncmd 1
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
2020-09-03 08:38:54.561836 > HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 12
    LE Read Remote Used Features Complete
      status 0x00 handle 64
      Features: 0x3d 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
2020-09-03 08:38:54.561898 < HCI Command: LE Start Encryption (0x08|0x0019) plen 28
  40 00 2E D2 E4 15 52 0D 83 CA 8E 39 FD 01 99 FE 2F 6F 2C 13
  E5 CA 36 09 36 D5 8C 99
2020-09-03 08:38:54.562285 > HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
    LE Start Encryption (0x08|0x0019) status 0x00 ncmd 1
2020-09-03 08:38:55.000536 > HCI Event: Encrypt Change (0x08) plen 4
    status 0x00 handle 64 encrypt 0x01
2020-09-03 08:38:55.007356 < ACL data: handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 7
    ATT: MTU req (0x02)
      client rx mtu 517
2020-09-03 08:38:55.098466 > ACL data: handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 7
    ATT: MTU resp (0x03)
      server rx mtu 65
2020-09-03 08:38:55.098818 < ACL data: handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 11
    ATT: Read By Group req (0x10)
      start 0x0001, end 0xffff
      type-uuid 0x2800
2020-09-03 08:38:55.195679 > HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5
    handle 64 packets 2
2020-09-03 08:38:55.196161 > ACL data: handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 18
    ATT: Read By Group resp (0x11)
      attr handle 0x0001, end group handle 0x0007
      value 0x00 0x18
      attr handle 0x0008, end group handle 0x0008
      value 0x01 0x18
2020-09-03 08:38:55.196438 < ACL data: handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 11
    ATT: Read By Group req (0x10)
      start 0x0009, end 0xffff
      type-uuid 0x2800
2020-09-03 08:38:55.294147 > ACL data: handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 26
    ATT: Read By Group resp (0x11)
      attr handle 0x0009, end group handle 0xffff
      value 0xe4 0x6d 0xdc 0x75 0xbf 0xdd 0xe5 0x84 0x1a 0x42 0x0e 0x0b 0x01 0x00 0xbd 0x98
2020-09-03 08:38:55.494758 > HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5
    handle 64 packets 1
2020-09-03 08:38:55.732258 > HCI Event: Disconn Complete (0x05) plen 4
    status 0x00 handle 64 reason 0x08
    Reason: Connection Timeout
```

**UPDATE**

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/mowlinette $ sudo bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# show
Controller B8:27:EB:9C:6F:8A (public)
        Name: raspberrypi
        Alias: raspberrypi
        Class: 0x00000000
        Powered: yes
        Discoverable: no
        Pairable: yes
        UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        Modalias: usb:v1D6Bp0246d0532
        Discovering: no
[bluetooth]# info 04:EE:03:B1:47:DF
Device 04:EE:03:B1:47:DF (public)
        Name: 315X
        Alias: 315X
        Paired: no
        Trusted: no
        Blocked: no
        Connected: no
        LegacyPairing: no
        UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Vendor specific           (98bd0001-0b0e-421a-84e5-ddbf75dc6de4)
        ManufacturerData Key: 0x0426
        ManufacturerData Value:
  05 04 03 19 fe 0b                                ......
```

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ service bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-09-03 11:08:24 BST; 1s ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 1851 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 2200)
   Memory: 692.0K
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─1851 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Sep 03 11:08:24 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Sep 03 11:08:24 raspberrypi bluetoothd[1851]: Bluetooth daemon 5.50
Sep 03 11:08:24 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Sep 03 11:08:24 raspberrypi bluetoothd[1851]: Starting SDP server
Sep 03 11:08:24 raspberrypi bluetoothd[1851]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
Sep 03 11:08:24 raspberrypi bluetoothd[1851]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Sep 03 11:08:24 raspberrypi bluetoothd[1851]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
```

Sap-driver fix using `--noplugin=sap` :

```
sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service
ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd --noplugin=sap
```

**EDIT 2**

**btmgmt info 3B/zero**

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo btmgmt info
Index list with 1 item
hci0:   Primary controller
        addr B8:27:EB:27:D6:7A version 7 manufacturer 15 class 0x000000
        supported settings: powered connectable fast-connectable discoverable bondable link-security ssp br/edr hs le advertising secure-conn debug-keys privacy static-addr 
        current settings: powered bondable ssp br/edr le secure-conn 
        name raspberrypi
        short name
```

**btmgmt info 3B+**

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo btmgmt info
Index list with 1 item
hci0:   Primary controller
        addr B8:27:EB:9C:6F:8A version 9 manufacturer 305 class 0x000000
        supported settings: powered connectable fast-connectable discoverable bondable link-security ssp br/edr hs le advertising secure-conn debug-keys privacy static-addr 
        current settings: powered bondable ssp br/edr le secure-conn 
        name raspberrypi
        short name
```

**FIX**

It's was due to a bug in the bluetooth firmware :

https://github.com/RPi-Distro/firmware-nonfree/issues/8#issuecomment-673309390

Comment: Side note: hcidump is one of the eight tools that have been deprecated by BlueZ https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/commit/?id=b1eb2c4cd057624312e0412f6c4be000f7fc3617   The currently supported tool is `btmon`.

Comment: thanks @ukBaz , look like there might be an issue with Sap driver

Comment: @ukBaz fixed the sap driver with flag --noplugin=sap, but still being disconnected due to Connection Timeout (0x08). From time to time it works but most of the time it trigger a timeout. I guess there is a difference somewhere between Pi3B/Zero and Pi3B+

Comment: Only the version change, on Pi 3B+ it's 4.2 while on Zero/3B it's 4.1 right ?

Comment: Thanks @ukBaz I’ll try with disabled Wi-Fi and upgraded firmware

Comment: Please don't answer the question within your Question. Instead create an answer with the solution and mark it as the accepted one with a click on the tick on its left side after two days. That prevents your Question from being shown as a unsolved Post to the community and saves them/us a lot of work.

Comment: For anyone who's still interested, [this recent post in the RPi distro on GitHub](https://github.com/RPi-Distro/pi-bluetooth/issues/15#issuecomment-770242435) may be of interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look like the root cause is due to the new Bluetooth chip (4.2) implemented since Pi 3B+

https://github.com/RPi-Distro/firmware-nonfree/issues/8

On Pi 3B+/4 I had to downgrade to bluez version: 5.50-1.2~deb10u1 via:

```
wget http://ftp.hk.debian.org/debian/pool/main/b/bluez/bluez_5.50-1.2~deb10u1_armhf.deb
sudo apt install ./bluez_5.50-1.2~deb10u1_armhf.deb
```

This fix break Bluetooth on Pi Zero/Pi 3B which was working properly on 5.50-1.2~deb10u1+rpt1.

Comment: I'm unclear on exactly what it was that fixed your issue: 1. Your comment says, "disabled WiFi and upgraded firmware"; your answer doesn't mention WiFi. 2. The link to github issue/cmt says it's for firmware for Pi4B, but your issue was 3B+?? 3. Blindly following the comment in your answer on my Pi3B+ took me **FROM:**: `Version: 5.50-1.2~deb10u1+rpt2`  **TO:** `Version: 5.50-1.2~deb10u1` - a downgrade?!

Comment: Correct, downgrade to Version: 5.50-1.2~deb10u1. Pi 4B and 3B+ share the same Bluetooth chip. Notice: this "fix" break Bluetooth on Pi Zero and I guess on Pi 3B too.

Comment: OK, thanks. Your answer would be much more helpful if you'll add some details. I'll upvote your answer (my current upvote will remain) if you'll do so. As it's written now, reading the github issue you referenced confuses things b/c that comment is re RPi 4B - not 3B+.